# How to properly detect pages in DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).

What I am trying to do is: by using one of the columns values, get page number, where this value is located.

I have tried this: [jumpToData()](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData())
BUT this didn't work out. The reason is that

```
var pos = this.column(column, { order: 'current' }).data().indexOf(data);
```

in `jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()'` returns value >=0 ONLY if I was placed on page where value was. 
For example, I want to detect page where needed value is, but I am staying on another page, so to detect value on... page 3, I need to go to this page and only then I can detect it, which makes no sence at all.

What I need to do, is: by staying on pirst page, using value from another pages, detect those pages numbers and then navigate to them:

```
$('#Grid_grid').DataTable().page(PageNumber).draw(false);
```

How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

Got some idea (several changes in jumpToData()):

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()', function (data, column) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.page.info().pages; i++) {
        var test = this.page(i).column(column, { order: 'current' }).data().indexOf(data);

        if (test >= 0) {
            this.page(i).draw(false);
            return this;
        }
    }
    return this;
});
```

**(EDIT 2: idea didn't paid off, no difference)**

BUT now I got second issue:
None methods of datatable works in .cshtml page.
For example I need to get overall page count. I doing this:

```
$('#Grid_grid').DataTable().page.info().pages;
```

and this return me 0;
Meanwhile, putting it in to console (Chrome F12) works fine (returns 5). Whats the matter?

**EDIT 3:**
Came up with this:

```
function LoadPage(value) {
    var table = $('#Grid_grid').DataTable();
    var pageNumber = table.search(value).page();
    table.page(pageNumber).draw(false);
}
```

Looks promising BUT, I still cant validate it because in console DataTable methods are working, but in .cshtml no. (search() or page() returns nothing).

**EDIT 4:**

Moved issue to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936226/what-to-do-when-datatable-properties-methods-are-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

> **CAUSE**

Your new API method `page.jumpToData()` tries to query all pages data because second argument [`selector-modifier`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) in `column()` API method has property `page: 'all'` by default. As written it will always stay on first page.

> **SOLUTION**

There is original [`page.jumpToData()`](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData%28%29) plug-in posted by Allan Jardine, creator of DataTables. It works as intended and can be used instead of your modification to avoid unnecessary iterations.

```js
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()', function (data, column) {
    var pos = this.column(column, {
        order: 'current'
    }).data().indexOf(data);

    if (pos >= 0) {
        var page = Math.floor(pos / this.page.info().length);
        this.page(page).draw(false);
    }

    return this;
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnmsc66m/1/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

In the demo above I added `console.log("Number of pages", table.page.info().pages);` just to demonstrate that API method works. However they may work because I have HTML-sourced data.

If you have Ajax-sourced data, you need to query number of pages only when data has been loaded. Use [`initComplete`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option to define a callback function that will be called when your table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn.

Comment: As I understand... original method should work but... because in my solution is not working, that means that issue I got (described in edit 2) are preventing it... Hm, what kind of reason can be there when after dataTable creation, mentods on .cshtml are not reaction anymore (page or search and etc) (propably should move this to another question)? And... can you please comment moment with initComplete - what exactly are supposed to be there?

Comment: In Edit 4 I moved issue part to another question (because description became too big)